How to write NestJS callback that wraps around all incoming HTTP requests
How can I get a wrapper callback for all HTTP requests similar to how express does it so that when an 100ms long HTTP request comes in I can e.g. log 2 lines at beginning and end of request:
0ms HTTP request start
100ms Response delivered

Both app.useGlobalInterceptors() and MiddlewareConsumer.apply() take callbacks which end at first milliseconds of Request start.

The following works as expected.
@Injectable()
export class LoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log('start')
    req.on('end', () => {
      console.log('end')
    })
    next()
  }
}

export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(LoggerMiddleware),
  }
}

Based on this opentelemetry example.
Without using req.end event, as soon as we call “await” anywhere in the route, then the event loop jumps to sync next() function.
Then our middleware code "ends" before HTTP request ends and async code executes after middleware "end".
In order to get console.log("end") at end of HTTP request, we could make all routes/middleware async and await all next() calls.
Thanks to user Script on NestJS Discord for helping me with this!
